# Heroku always send a response as html instead a json with the data expected

Tags: node.js, heroku, nginx, http-headers

I did deploy my api application to Heroku and it is running normally on dyno.

My problem is when I try to do a request using POSTMAN or my FrontEnd Application, Heroku server always returns that HTML content:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
<meta name="VERSION" content="">
<meta name="DATA" content="fwdnode3.registrar-servers.com (208.64.122.246)">
<link href=" " rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
<title></title>
</head>
<frameset rows='100%, *' frameborder=no framespacing=0 border=0>
<frame src="https://epiphany-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products" name=mainwindow frameborder=no framespacing=0 marginheight=0 marginwidth=0></frame>
</frameset>
<noframes><h2>Your browser does not support frames. We recommend upgrading your browser.</h2><br><br>
<center>Click <a href="https://epiphany-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/products" >here</a> to enter the site.</center>
</noframes>
</html>
</pre>
```

The http code that response above is 200(OK) and the response header is:

```
Server: nginx
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2016 12:56:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
```

But when I do a request using a browser, Heroku server returns the data correctly.

Well, sometimes I receive a 400 (Bad Resquest) code as well, from that Nginx server.

My api is a node application, so I do not understand why that Nginx server is intercepting and sending responses instead my Node App.

**Edit - added description**

This is NodeJS code in my api:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    consign = require('consign'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cors = require('cors'),
    compression = require('compression'),
    port = process.env.PORT || 9000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));

consign({ cwd: 'project' })
    .include('common/config')
    .then('common/helpers')
    // middlewares should be loaded individually
    .then('common/middleware/authenticationV1.js')
    .then('modules/products/validationsV1.js')
    .then('modules/products/repositoryV1.js')
    .then('modules/products/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/products/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/products/routesV1.js')
    .then('modules/categories/repositoryV1.js')
    .then('modules/categories/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/categories/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/categories/routesV1.js')
    .then('modules/checkout')
    .then('modules/colors/repositoryV1.js')
    .then('modules/colors/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/colors/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/colors/routesV1.js')
    .then('modules/sizes/repositoryV1.js')
    .then('modules/sizes/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/sizes/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/sizes/routesV1.js')
    .then('modules/users/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/users/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/users/routesV1.js')
    .then('modules/adminUsers/repositoryV1.js')
    .then('modules/adminUsers/modelV1.js')
    .then('modules/adminUsers/controllerV1.js')
    .then('modules/adminUsers/routesV1.js')
    //the error handler has to be last middleware loaded, pay attention :)
    .then('common/middleware/error-handlerV1.js')
    .into(app);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('running server port %s', port);
});
```

Just to test, send a GET request to that endpoint:
    `http://api.epiphany.store/api/v1/products`

**Edit - added description**

`modules/colors/routesV1.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const colors = app.modules.colors.controllerV1;
    const auth = app.common.middleware.authenticationV1;

    app.get('/api/v1/colors', colors.getAll);
    app.get('/api/v1/colors/:id', colors.get);
    app.post('/api/v1/colors', auth.admin, colors.post);
    app.put('/api/v1/colors', auth.admin, colors.put);
    app.delete('/api/v1/colors/:id', auth.admin, colors.delete);
}
```

`modules/colors/controllerV1.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const Colors = app.modules.colors.modelV1;

    this.getAll = (req, res, next) => {
        Colors.find()
            .then(result => {
                res.json(result);
            })
            .catch(err => next(err));
    };

    this.get = (req, res, next) => {
        Colors.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(result => {
                if (!result) {
                    res.status(404).end();    
                }

                res.json(result);
            })
            .catch(err => next(err));
    };

    this.post = (req, res, next) => {
        Colors.create(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                res.status(204).json(result);
            })
            .catch(err => next(err));
    };

    this.put = (req, res, next) => {
        Colors.update(req.body)
            .then(result => {
                res.status(200).end();
            })
            .catch(err => next(err));
    };

    this.delete = (req, res, next) => {
        Colors.findById(req.params.id)
            .then(result => {
                if (!result) {
                    res.status(404).end();
                }

                result.remove(err => {
                    if (err) {
                        next(err);
                    }

                    res.status(200).end();
                });
            })
            .catch(error => next(error));
    };

    return this;
}
```

`modules/colors/modelV1.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const mongoose = app.common.config.mongooseV1;
    const repository = app.modules.colors.repositoryV1;
    const Product = app.modules.products.modelV1;
    const validationError = app.common.helpers.errors.validationV1;

    repository.pre('remove', function (next) {
        Product.count({ 'stock.color': this._id })
            .then(quantity => {
                if (!quantity) {
                    next();
                }

                let error = validationError(this, {
                    action: 'remove',
                    errors: {
                        impossibleToRemove: {
                            message: 'This registry is being used by others registries'
                        }
                    }
                });

                next(error);
            })
            .catch(error => next(error));
    });

    return mongoose.model('colors', repository);
}
```

`modules/colors/repositoryV1.js`

```
'use strict';

module.exports = app => {
    const mongoose = app.common.config.mongooseV1;

    const schema = mongoose.Schema({
        description: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Required field'],
            unique: [true, 'Unique field']
        },
        color: {
            type: String,
            required: [true, 'Required field']
        }
    });

    return schema;
}
```

The workflow is `route -> controller -> model -> repository`.

Improvements that workflow structure is very welcome :)

Thank you for all help!

Comment: Paste the code that is responsible for sending the data. The code that is on the NodeJS side.

Comment: Hello @David, I've modified my question.

Comment: We are almost there :) We need the content of one of those JS file that process the request.

Comment: Do you mean a js code in my FrontEnd Application?

Comment: More in the line of `modules/colors/repositoryV1.js`, the code that sends the response to the browser with the status code and the body content. `res.send("hello world");`

Comment: I have modified the question with all workflow of a request

Comment: No offense, by the way you designed you app is quite original :). For example if you used the simple expressJS framework, you would have sent the response by typing `response.status(200); response.json({});` - done, and the framework would had know that the object that you are sending should be stringifyed etc. I highly recommend you check https://expressjs.com. Sorry for not being able to help you in this case more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem, by following way:

```
httpProxy.createProxyServer({
    target: 'http://my.app.com',
    toProxy: true,
    changeOrigin: true,
    xfwd: true
});
```

Heroku has a proxy to redirect for my app, I have fixed my problem adding the `toProxy` and `changeOrigin` properties.

Ah, yeah I am using the that Node module https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

I hope that answer help someone!